# Installing numpy on Amazon EC2 virtualenv

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, amazon-ec2, virtualenv

I'm trying to build a virtualenv that uses python27 in a virtualenv on an Amazon EC2.  Research on the web indicated messing with the preinstalled Python26 is a bad idea so I wanted to work in a safe virtual env.  Here are all of my commands starting from a fresh instance on EC2

```
sudo easy_install python27
sudo easy_install virtualenv
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
mkdir virt_env
virtualenv -p python27 virt_env/py27
```

And this all seems to work great.  When I activate my virtualenv Python27 is the default, and outside of it Python26 is the default.  So far so good.  Next I tried iPython in the virtualenv

```
source virt_env/py27/bin/activate
pip install ipython
```

This works great, again ipython is available in the virtualenv and not available outside of it.  However when I go to install numpy in the virtualenv I get the follwing:

```
pip install numpy
// Lots of output that I won't paste all of it, main error below
SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong because I've always installed numpy on virtualenv this way.  Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

EDIT:  I've also tried using:

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

in the virtualenv.  Still no help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was able to answer my own question.  To install the python dev correctly I needed:

```
sudo yum install python27-devel
```

Comment: @sedaviw. I am interested in this question and answer. Do you have sudo privileges to install software on the EC2 instances? Do you hae any pointers on where I can find more info on this?

Comment: @user815423426 When you start off an EC2 you do have sudo privileges.  To install any given package you use `sudo yum install <package>`.  If you have questions regarding a specific package you can generally google it and find explanations on how to install them